# PHP method signature has no parameters method call has one parameter no warning

Tags: php, methods, signature

Hello I am trying to make a simple class that has a method with no parameters. With method call I am putting in one parameter to fail a test but the test passes. And if I run the code in browser everything runs with no warning. I am on a development environment so php should detect such violations.

This is the method signature

```
    public function getServiceDetail(): ServiceDetail
    {
        ...
    }
```

This is the call

```
...

$this->repository->getServiceDetail(1);

...
```

The result of the above is just fine I get the detail from the logic that is in the method no warnings or errors.

Edit: If I put wrong type into signature of the method I get the proper error since I have `strict_types` on.

Comment: So, are you trying to get a test fail when you call this method with a non declarated parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP doesn't care about that because all php functions are variadic by nature. This is why [`func_get_args`](http://php.net/func-get-args) exists. Anything you hand to a php function/method is assumed valid unless otherwise explicitly defined as invalid. In other words, you must define a prototype and the call must then explicitly defy that prototype for it be considered invalid.

For example:

```
function foo(Array $bar, String $baz) {
    var_dump(func_get_args());
}

foo([1], "quix", new stdclass); // is perfectly legal in php
```

You get

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    int(1)
  }
  [1]=>
  string(4) "quix"
  [2]=>
  object(stdClass)#1 (0) {
  }
}
```

[From the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list):

> PHP has support for variable-length argument lists in user-defined functions. This is implemented using the `...` token in PHP 5.6 and later, and using the `func_num_args()`, `func_get_arg()`, and `func_get_args()` functions in PHP 5.5 and earlier.